# iOS: Issues with background uploading large files

Tags: ios, swift, uploading

I have an app that records and uploads large files ( up to 5gigs each )

After the recordings are done the user triggers an action to begin the file uploads.

The uploads are registered for background processing so they continue if the phone goes asleep.

I issues I am running into:

1. Random memory crashes on some files over 4 gigs
2. Unable to initiate a background upload while the app is already suspended.

So if user records a file between 4-5gigs the app will randomly crash while uploading. Multiple 5 gig files uploading at the same time also increases the chance of crashing.

We currently upload the files in sequence but ran into issue #2 from my list. If the user records multiple 5 gigs files, and puts the phone asleep, only the the first file will upload and the user has to reopen the app for the next file to begin processing.

I have attempted to use BackgroundTasks to see if it can trigger an upload but the background task never fires and I've read the only attempts to fire the background task if it thinks the user is about to use the phone.

I also tried using the urlSessionDidFinishEvents callback on uploadTask. But it never seemed to fire or at least it can't be used to call an API request.

Anyone have advice on initating background file uploads for large files?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are likely reaching system resource limits.  The system will eject your binary when this occurs; they are called Jetsam events.  I suggest you trigger a sysdiagnose event on your device (differs per device - usually pressing volume up, down, and side buttons together).

Then recover the logs from `Settings > Privacy > Analytics and Improvements > Analytics Data`

The file names begin with `sysdiagnose_YEAR.MONTH.DAY_*.`

After you copy the files over to your Mac (using the Share button in the iOS UI) you can then look at specifically what is being breached.

Please update your question with specific log information thus retrieved.

Lastly, it is worth implementing `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` since your app is probably using a lot of memory during such processing.

Comment: Cheers will test this out tomorrow and see what is being said!